# PHP: One column table to one-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have table like this:

```
random_num
----------
0
15
12
...
```

and I have query `SELECT random_num FROM table_name;`.

I want to fetch array in way like:

```
$row[0] = 0;
$row[1] = 15;
$row[2] = 12;
etc..
```

But PHP lets me only to fetch it in this way:

```
$row[0]['random_num'] = 0;
etc..
```

How to fetch it as I want?

Comment: I use `while` and mysql_fetch_assoc and then I assign it to array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
//PHP >= 5.3 
$row = array_map(function($n) {
   return $row['random_num'];
}, $row);

//PHP < 5.3
function map($n) {
  return $n['random_num'];
}

$row = array_map('map', $row);


//EDIT
$row = array_map('implode', $row) //thanks to hakre
```

Comment: You probably meant: `$row = array_map('implode', $row);` - works with all PHP versions out of the box.

Comment: Well the better point is, that you just fetch it that way from the database. But as the TS did not share any info how s/he is using the database, an answer can not be given.

Comment: Like if you're using PDO or mysqli to query the database. Those libraries have functions that will give you the array as you need it w/o changing it afterwards with another PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you couldn't just use `$row[0]['random_num']`, but if you really need to flatten the array:

```
foreach( $row as $index => $data ) {
    $row[ $index ] = $row[ $index ]['random_num'];
}
```